# php issue with inserting into sql

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpstorm

I am having an issue inserting into mysql db using php. 
specifically this code is giving me problems:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO '$mysql_database'.'$UsersTable' ('firstName', 'lastName', 'password', 'email','userType')VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$password','$email','$userType')";
```

I can't seem to find the error with syntax here. All the information to me seems correct. where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Wrap off quotes from `table and column` name instead use `backtick`

Comment: Remove $mysql_database and start a connection before your query

Comment: @Saty what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Wha is the value of `'$mysql_database'.'$UsersTable' ` ?? from where you get it??

Comment: can you show compliled query

Comment: what's the real sql you insert to db? show the error code,please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $mysql_database.$UsersTable (firstName, lastName, password, email,userType)VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$password','$email','$userType')";
```

remove Quote from table column

Comment: that hasn't worked either, still getting syntax error .

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $mysql_database.$UsersTable (firstName, lastName, password, email,userType)VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$password','$email','$userType')";
```

Comment: @Aboogie you may use the above query i edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can't use single Quote from table column name so remove it

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $mysql_database.$UsersTable (firstName, lastName, password, email,userType)VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$password','$email','$userType')";
```

otherwise use this way

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $mysql_database.$UsersTable (`firstName`, `lastName`, `password`, `email`,`userType`)VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$password','$email','$userType')";
```